# Amazon Alexa Proactive Events request in Python flask-ask

Tags: python, python-requests, alexa-skills-kit, flask-ask

I am trying to make a request to the [Proactive Events API](https://developer.amazon.com/de/docs/smapi/proactive-events-api.html?&sc_category=Owned&sc_channel=WB&sc_campaign=proactiveevents&sc_publisher=launch&sc_content=Content&sc_funnel=Discover&sc_country=WW&sc_medium=Owned_WB_proactiveevents_launch_Content_Discover_WW_unknown&sc_segment=unknown#call-proactive) by using the requests module of Python.

However I always receive a response that the scope is invalid.
Can anyone help? What am I doing wrong? My code looks like this:

```
@ask.launch
def launch():
    content_type = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8"
    client_id = "amzn1.application-oa2-client.6a48XXXXXXX408"
    client_secret = "592XXXXxxxxxxx6"
    scope = "alexa::proactive_events"
    grant_type = "client_credentials"

    data = {"grant_type": grant_type, "client_id": client_id, "client_secret": client_secret, "scope": scope}
    r = requests.post("https://api.amazon.com/auth/O2/token", data=data, headers={"content-type": content_type})

    speech = render_template("welcome")
    reprompt = render_template("welcome_reprompt")
    return question(speech).reprompt(reprompt)
```

That is the response I get:

```
{'error_description': 'The request has an invalid parameter : scope', 'error': 'invalid_scope'}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since one of the reason you get the invalid scope is that you dont have the events included in your skill manifest I include some steps here. I found quite cumbersome to use the SMAPI to update the skill manifest so instead I used ask cli.

- install ask-cli: get authorization code for your amazon acount. In my case the backend is not an AWS lambda function but an external web server
- get the skill manifest in json format:
  `ask api get-skill -s "amzn1.ask.skill.ZZZYYYZZ" --stage development > skill.json`
- Add the notifications permission and the events elements to the manifest:

  `{
      "name": "alexa::devices:all:notifications:write"
   }`

  and

  `"events": {
     "publications": [
       {
           "eventName": "AMAZON.AAABBBCC"
       }
      ],
      "endpoint":  {
          "uri": "https://XXXYYYZZ:443/whatevercontext"
       }
  }`
- update the manifest: 
  `ask api update-skill -s "amzn1.ask.skill.ZZZYYYZZ" --stage development -f skill.json`

  - enable the notifications in the alexa app for your specific skill

Now you should be able to get the token and next step is to send the notification to the device

Comment: would you be able to put down the steps to update skill manifest using SMAPI as well?

Comment: Thanks you so much. Saved a lot of time. (y)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried making the API call via any other method? I just tried that with Postman and it worked for me.

My Python's a bit rusty, but here's the self generated code from Postman for Python. May be this should help?

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("api,amazon,com")

payload = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=amzn1.application-oa2-client.whatever-value&client_secret=client-secret&scope=alexa%3A%3Aproactive_events&undefined="

headers = {
  'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}

conn.request("POST", "auth,O2,token", payload, headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 0):

As Karthik asked previously have you tried the call via postman? I first suggest trying to via postman before you trying to code it.

If the issue still persists its most likely because you haven't included the necessary permissions required for Proactive Events in your Skill Manifest.
To add the necessary permissions to Skill Manifest you need to use the Skill Management API & ASK Cli.
Follow this section of the documentation and visit the links referenced there to correctly add the required permissions to your skill - https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/proactive-events-api.html#onboard-smapi

Once you have successfully added the *events* and *publications* with a skill schema you should be able to successfully generate a token.
Please feel to ask if you want me to elaborate more on the exact steps.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have tried and it worked:

```py
amazon_token_url = "https://api.amazon.com/auth/O2/token"
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'}
body = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=amzn1.application-oa2-client.XXXYYYZZ&client_secret=ZZZYYYXXX&scope=alexa::proactive_events"
log.debug("Sending token request with body: %s", body)
resp = requests.post(amazon_token_url, data=body, headers=headers)
resp_json = json.loads(resp.content.decode('utf-8'))

if (resp.status_code < 299) and (resp.status_code > 199):
   log.debug("token received from Amazon")
   log.debug("Content : %s", resp.content)
   token = resp_json["access_token"]
   return token
```