# Alexa Skill Proactive Events Python Implementation

Tags: python, python-2.7, alexa-skills-kit

I was wondering if someone can help me point in the right direction to implement Proactive Events to my already existing Alexa Skill. My Code is running on AWS Lambda on python. If someone can help me with a general example of implementation, that would be great. Needs to be in Python.
Thank you!

Comment: This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53795375/amazon-alexa-proactive-events-request-in-python-flask-ask  reviews the steps of 1) the need for the skills manifest, and also some python code for creating the call to retrieve the token to create the notification.

Comment: @ChuckLaPress how can I edit skill manifest using developer console?

Comment: When utilizing the ask-cli your skill will be produced with a file at the root level named skill.json that will be the json representation of the skill see this: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/skill-manifest.html the easiest method may be to install ask-cli and clone your current skill. see: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/ask-cli-command-reference.html#clone-command otherwise produce the file manually. I would also suggest this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oMcHTMZDTVQ to get a good overview of the implementation process.